# Error System.NullReferenceException al querer setear una variable en un objeto

Tags: c#, poo, mvc

Esty seteando informacion en una variable de un objeto y no entiendo por que me aparece el siguiente erro:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
```

Como pueden ver hice una instancia del objeto antes de empezar a setearlo, en que estoy fallando?
Aquí el codigo:

```
ContratoPDF pdf = new ContratoPDF();
con.CARGO = pdf.contrato.CARGO;
```

`con.Cargo` si me trae el valor que es "ADMINISTRADOR" el problema es cunado lo setea en `pdf.contrato.CARGO;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entiendo que contrato es un clase dentro del objeto pdf y que este no está instanciado. Deberías hacer un algo como:

```
ContratoPDF pdf = new ContratoPDF();
Pdf.contrato = new contrato();
con.CARGO = pdf.contrato.CARGO;
```

Comment: No sabia que también se instanciaban las clases de un objeto, muchas gracias!! y perdón por el fallo básico.